# jquery wmd editors

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I just spent a few hours researching editors. Read 100 or more posts about the wmd editor used by stackoverflow and I still don't know where things stand. Seems like the editor debate will go on forever.

Now I am wondering if it would be better for me to use an editor based on jquery. But I'm not sure what's out there.

Has anyone experience with the latest jquery editors? If so can you recommend some.

thanks

Micel

Answer (score 0):

The WYSIWYG debate will probably rage on for a long time. While I've implemented WMD myself on a very large traffic, low editor requirements project, it won't suite everybody.

I think the thing that will make your job easier is if you list what you want out of it first.

- Do you need more than just rich text?
- Do you want it to fail gracefully in
  different browser situations?
- How much time do you have to get the
  right answer for clensing the html
  that's being submitted?

and most of all...
**How public is your site?**

I have used everything from FCK to telerik's RADEditor on CMS projects as I can (mostly) trust it's users. I have used WMD on a user to user site as I definitely can't trust users and I only want basic rich text editing (just like this site).

Comment: The site will be public. I am looking for an editor very similar to the one used here on Stackoverflow. I would just like to be sure it's supported and the latest with no license issues.

Comment: Yeah I had to dig around to get the implementation I wanted. WMD is free, but I also had to add Jeff Atwood's whitelist clensing routines and then I had to write my own jquery wrapper for it. Was worth the effort tho as it's very very lightweight and safe for public sites.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link. They provide demos for 14 jQuery and non jQuery editors. http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/14-jquery-and-non-jquery-rich-text-editors/